# After entering valid credentials application showing invalid session timeout

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

Recently I upgraded Spring and Spring Security to 5.5.7 version. If we enter valid credentials it is through but finally it is showing session is timedout please try again. Before upgradation it is working fine.

**`login.jsp`**

```
. <form role="form" id="loginForm" action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" ></c:url>" method="post">
```

**`spring-security.xml`**

```xml
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
            create-session="ifRequired" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" >

            <security:form-login login-page="/login-fail?error"
                    default-target-url="/home" authentication-failure-url="/login-fail?error"
                    username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" />

             <security:logout invalidate-session="true"
                    logout-success-url="/logout?logout" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
                    delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />

            <!-- <security:session-management
                    invalid-session-url="/login-fail?error-timeout">
                    <security:concurrency-control
                            max-sessions="50" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
            </security:session-management> -->

            <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/login-fail?error-timeout"
                    session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
                    <security:concurrency-control
                            max-sessions="50" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false"
                            expired-url="/login-fail?error-timeout" />
            </security:session-management>


            <security:remember-me
            token-validity-seconds="3600"
            remember-me-parameter="remember"
            data-source-ref="dataSource"
            />

            <security:headers>
                    <security:frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN" />
            </security:headers>
```

**getting authentication is success but it is redirecting to the access denied. you are not allowed to access this page**

**log**

```
[ DEBUG ][ 27 Sep 2022 11:57:20,302 ] [ AspectControllerLogging ] : Arguments passed: [org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied, SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@18f8cbc0], org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterResponse@7e4fc76a, en]
[ ERROR ][ 27 Sep 2022 11:57:20,307 ] [ ExceptionHandlingController ] : Access is denied
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:73) ~[spring-security-core-5.5.7.jar:5.5.7]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:238) ~[spring-security-core-5.5.7.jar:5.5.7]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:208) ~[spring-security-core-5.5.7.jar:5.5.7]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:58) ~[spring-security-core-5.5.7.jar:5.5.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at com.elitecore.sm.iam.controller.HomeController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a8dbedab.home(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
```

**Home Controller**

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('HOME')")
@RequestMapping(value = { ControllerConstants.HOME,ControllerConstants.SSOHOME }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView home(@RequestParam(value = "isRsaSuccess", required=false) String isRsaSuccess,HttpServletRequest request)  throws StaffUniqueContraintException,SMException{
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    if(isRsaSuccess==null)
        isRsaSuccess="no";
    User springUserBeanHome = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    
    if(Boolean.parseBoolean(MapCache.getConfigValueAsObject(SystemParametersConstant.SSO_ENABLE).toString())){
        springUserBeanHome=staffAutoritiesForSSO(springUserBeanHome);
    }
    request.getSession().setAttribute(BaseConstants.USER_NAME, springUserBeanHome.getUsername());
    if(staffService.isLDAPStaff(springUserBeanHome.getUsername()) && !isRsaSuccess.equals("yes") && Boolean.TRUE.toString().equals((String)MapCache.getConfigValueAsObject(SystemParametersConstant.RSA_CALL))){
        model.setViewName(ViewNameConstants.RSA_OTP_PAGE);
    }else{
    
    model.setViewName(ViewNameConstants.HOME_PAGE);
    model.addObject("isRenew", false);
    model.addObject(BaseConstants.REQUEST_ACTION_TYPE,BaseConstants.DASHBOARD);
```

Comment: The problem is `@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('HOME')")`. So your user has not the role.

Comment: Add the role to your user or remove `@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('HOME')")` .

Comment: if we remove @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('HOME')") it is working but if we add instead of HOME -> ROLE_HOME it is not working. in my application  i used @PreAuthorize annoation in hundreds of places. please suggest on this

Comment: *did you mean addling @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_HOME')")* No, you have to add the role to your user.

Comment: @dur - but roles are already available to user and one more thing if we use instead of hasAnyRole() -> hasAutority() it is working. i am new to these two annotations. possible suggest on this also

Comment: @dur- after login i was getting 404 page not found for all pages error is **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING** . why we are getting this for all pages ?